# RTSP connection issue on IP Camera

Tags: python, connection, rtsp, ip-camera

I have flir blackfly s bfs-pge-04s2c-cs model ip camera. I have poe injector that is connected to router and to camera. I can find the camera ip. My problem is I cannot connect with rtsp.

with EasyPySpin I can get a frame with the code below.

```
import cv2
import EasyPySpin

cap = EasyPySpin.VideoCapture(0)
print(cap.get(0))

for i in range(100):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

cv2.imwrite("frame.png", frame)
    
cap.release()
```

I need rtsp connection for my other processes the ip is shown with the matched mac adress in my system. I tried like that

```
import cv2
import os

RTSP_URL = 'rtsp://192.168.1.240'

os.environ['OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS'] = 'rtsp_transport;udp'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print('Cannot open RTSP stream')
    exit(-1)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    print('hehe')
    cv2.imshow('RTSP stream', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I cannot make a connection with this code.

Comment: Does it show any message in the console?

Comment: @jvx8ss it says cannot stream rtsp connection after a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Blackfly S GigE does not support rtsp streaming. It uses GVSP  that is a protocol for gige streaming.

I manually created an rtsp server with simple rtsp server written in Go language then used gstreamer pipeline with aravis plugin.

```
gst-launch-1.0 aravissrc ! video/x-raw,format=RGB ! videoconvert !  video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast ! rtspclientsink protocols=tcp location=rtsp://localhost:8554/flir
```

Answer (score 0):

To verify that the RTSP binding is correct, use a third-party application. In my case I used "VLC media player". If you have the correct link but it doesn't work in Python, check that you have downloaded ffmpeg. In my case, that was the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).